# Plotting a function of two variables based on data from a file

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose the values of a function are written line by line in the file in the form `x y f(x, y)` and I read this file into the list of lists `[ [x1, y1, f(x1, y1)], ..., [xN, yN, f(xN, yN)] ]`:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = [[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in file]
```

The question is how to plot this function.

I managed to write a program (see below) that implements the task (the values for `data` are taken as an example), but it looks too complicated and, it seems to me, there is a more elegant solution.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 3]]
x, y, _ = np.array(data).T.tolist()

x = list(set(x))
y = list(set(y))

def f(x, y):
    for val in data:
        if x == val[0] and y == val[1]:
            return val[2]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = [[f(x_, y_) for x_ in x] for y_ in y]

cp = plt.contourf(Y, X, Z)
plt.colorbar(cp)

plt.show()
```

Therefore, I think it is more correct to ask how to solve the problem gracefully, elegantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to significantly speed up the filling of `Z`. The solution, of course, is not elegant.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 3]]
x, y, _ = np.array(data).T.tolist()

x = list(set(x))
y = list(set(y))

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

#####
Z = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))

x_ind = {xx[1] : xx[0] for xx in enumerate(x)}
y_ind = {yy[1] : yy[0] for yy in enumerate(y)}

for d in data:
    xx, yy, zz = d
    Z[x_ind[xx], y_ind[yy]] = zz
#####

cp = plt.contourf(Y, X, Z)
plt.colorbar(cp)

plt.show()
```

I compare these two approaches with a simple code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import time


def f1(data, x, y):
    for val in data:
        if x == val[0] and y == val[1]:
            return val[2]


def init1(data, x, y):
    Z = [[f1(data, x_, y_) for x_ in x] for y_ in y]

    return Z


def init2(data, x, y):
    Z = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))

    x_ind = {xx[1] : xx[0] for xx in enumerate(x)}
    y_ind = {yy[1] : yy[0] for yy in enumerate(y)}

    for d in data:
        xx, yy, zz = d
        Z[x_ind[xx], y_ind[yy]] = zz

    return Z


def test(n):
    data = []

    x = y = [nn / n for nn in range(n+1)]

    for xx in x:
        for yy in y:
            data.append([xx, yy, 0.])

    t1 = time.time()
    init1(data, x, y)
    dt1 = time.time() - t1

    t2 = time.time()
    init2(data, x, y)
    dt2 = time.time() - t2

    print(f'n = {n:5d} ; t1 = {dt1:10.3f} s ; t2 = {dt2:10.3f} s')


def main():
    n = 10

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        try:
            n = int(sys.argv[1])
        except:
            print(f'Can not convert "{sys.argv[1]}" to integer')
            exit(0)

    if n <= 0:
        print(f'n is negative or equal zero')
        exit(0)

    test(n)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Without specifying the characteristics of the machine on which the program was run, I will only give the result of its work for `n = 100` and `n = 200`:

```
$ python test.py 100 ; python test.py 200
n =   100 ; t1 =      1.092 s ; t2 =      0.001 s
n =   200 ; t1 =     19.312 s ; t2 =      0.005 s
```

Of course, this is still an inefficient way. So, for example, it will take 2 seconds for a 4000 by 4000 grid.

I want to note that the new method works acceptably on small and medium amounts of data, and the operating time of `matplotlib` is significantly longer. On large amounts of data, the problems are primarily related to matplotlib.

I think that, although the solution is not elegant, it solves the problem at an acceptable speed. To be honest, I'm not even sure that the result can be significantly accelerated.